# simple backbone events not firing

Tags: backbone.js

I'm playing around with backbone.js for the first time, but can't get the events to fire properly. Can somebody explain what I'm doing wrong?

Much appreciated!

in app.js loaded at the bottom of my html:

```
var Discussion = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        id: null,
        title: 'New discussion'
    },
    urlRoot: '/api/discussion'
});

var DiscussionCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Discussion,
    url: '/api/discussion'
});

var DiscussionView = Backbone.View.extend({   
   events: {
        'click .btnCreateDiscussion': 'create',
        'keypress #discussion_title': 'create'
   },

   initialize: function(){
        //this.$el = $("#form_discussion");
        this.template = _.template( $('#discussion-template').html() );
   },

   render: function(){
        console.log("rendering");
        return this;    
   },

   create: function(){
        console.log('creating a new discussion')
   }
});

var discussionView = new DiscussionView({ el: $("#form_discussion"), model: Discussion });
```

html:

```
<form action="" id="form_discussion" method="post">

<label for="discussion_title">Discussion Title</label>
<input type="text" id="discussion_title" name="discussion_title" />

<input class="btnCreateDiscussion" type="button" value="Create Discussion">
```

```
  <script type="text/template" id="discussion-template">
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
  </script>
```

Comment: Is there something that isn't working, I just set up this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xCEE6/4/), seems to be working fine.

Comment: Is the view initialization kept in `$(document).ready()` ?

Comment: The jsFiddle you created seems to be working just fine, but locally it's not firing my events. I'll investigate further and will report back.

Comment: The problem was that I had to use jQuery 2.x instead of the latest 1.x, not sure why. It didn't throw any errors when using 1.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was jQuery. The most recent 1.x release didn't work, but using the most recent 2.x release fixes the problem. It would be useful if anyone could explain why we should only use 2.x in this case?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Jbahx/. (check your backbone & underscore versions, and make sure the DOM is initialized)

About what you're doing wrong though:

- `model: Discussion` when instantiating your view. You have to give the view an instance of a model, not a class. If you give the view a model (optional), it's generally because you want to represent the data of a particular instance.
- Your render method is never called, but it's useless at the moment so that's not that big a problem.
- `this.template = _.template( $('#discussion-template').html() );` in the `initialize` method. Put this as a property of the view when extending so it'll be put in the prototype of your view (even if it seems to be a singleton here): `template: _.template( $('#discussion-template').html() ),`.

Comment: jQuery was the problem. Using the 2.x release instead of the most recent 1.x release fixes the problem. Cost me a lot of time ;)

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you must call Backbone.View.prototype.initialize in your overriden method to let Backbone initialize event listeners:

```
initialize: function(){
    //this.$el = $("#form_discussion");
    this.template = _.template( $('#discussion-template').html() );
    Backbone.View.prototype.initialize.call(this)
},
```

Second, render view in initialize - it isn't best practice. Use for this separate `render` method.

Comment: Don't need to call `Backbone.View.prototype.initialize.call(this)`, Backbone will call this method if it is set on the view. if you view the source of Backbone you will see that this methods is empty. Also from the docs _If the view defines an initialize function, it will be called when the view is first created._